# How can I merge two dictionaries on their values?

Tags: dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict_A = {"a": 25, "b": 2, "c": 4}
dict_B = {"r": 2, "t": 25, "g": 4}
```

I want to make a new dictionary, `dict_C`, that merges them on their values but makes dict_B's keys the new values, ie.

```
dict_C = {"a": "t", "b": "r", "c": "g"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make inverted dictionary from dict_A and dict_B and then do merge:

```
dict_A = {"a": 25, "b": 2, "c": 4}
dict_B = {"r": 2, "t": 25, "g": 4}

inv_dict_A = {v: k for k, v in dict_A.items()}
inv_dict_B = {v: k for k, v in dict_B.items()}

dict_C = {inv_dict_A[k]: inv_dict_B[k] for k in inv_dict_A if k in inv_dict_B}
print(dict_C)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 't', 'b': 'r', 'c': 'g'}
```

Comment: Ah shoot. I forgot to mention some of them have the same values in one dictionary...